# Как в строке заменить все символы из набора на пустое в C#?

Tags: c#

Можно ли написать как то компактнее данный фрагмент кода или нет?

```
string newString = oldString.Replace(" ","")
                                .Replace(" ", "")
                                .Replace("-", "")
                                .Replace(".", "")
                                .Replace(",", "")
                                .Replace("(", "")
                                .Replace(")", "")
                                .Replace("{", "")
                                .Replace("}", "")
                                .Replace("[", "")
                                .Replace("]", "")
                                .Replace("!", "")
                                .Replace("@", "")
                                .Replace("#", "")
                                .Replace("$", "")
                                .Replace("%", "")
                                .Replace("^", "")
                                .Replace("*", "")
                                .Replace("+", "")
                                .Replace("=", "")
                                .Replace(":", "")
                                .Replace(";", "")
                                .Replace("/", "")
                                .Replace(@"\", "");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [Regex.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx) - в указанной входной строке заменяет все строки, соответствующие шаблону регулярного выражения, указанной строкой замены.

```
  string input = "This @#$[ываыв] %is text with some test data %$ dsffs !@#$%";
  string pattern = "[-.,(){}@#$%^&*!+=:;/\\[\\]]+";
  string replacement = "";
  Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
  string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);

  // This @#$[ываыв] %is text with some test data %$ dsffs !@#$%
  Console.WriteLine("Original String: {0}", input);
  // This ываыв is text with some test data  dsffs
  Console.WriteLine("Replacement String: {0}", result);
```

http://ideone.com/CVYgJG

Я не знаток регулярок, но как пример, думаю, это поможет найти правильный путь.

Comment: Всем спасибо! Но я сделал еще короче string newString = Regex.Replace(oldString, "[-.,(){}@#$%^<>?&*!+=:;/\\[\\]]+", "");

Comment: @ArtemiyMVC я специально разделил, чтоб видно было что откуда берется. Но вы, конечно же, вправе сделать всё как душе угодно)  Главное регулярку составить правильно

Answer (score 2):

Как вам и советовали выше, воспользуйтесь регуляркой. Проблема вашего кода не только в его многословности и дублировании, но ещё и в том, что при каждом вызове Replace строка создаётся заново (в силу неизменяемости строк в C#). Поэтому если строки достаточно большие и/или этот код будет вызываться много раз, вы рискуете получить существенный оверхед на многократное пересоздание вашей строки. Не берусь судить, что там происходит в недрах `Regex.Replace`, но наверняка его алгоритм подходит к этому вопросу существенно экономнее, нежели многократный вызов `Replace` с пересозданием строки.

Comment: Да, `Regex.Replace` внутри пользуется `StringBuilder`'ом.

Answer (score 1):

Если количество вызовов и/или размеры строк достаточно велики, то рекомендую следующий метод, который существенно (в несколько раз) выигрывает по скорострельности у `Regex`:

```
private static string ClearString(string s)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.Length);
    foreach (char c in s)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case ' ':
            case '\t':
            case '-':
            case '+':
            case '=':
            case '.':
            case ',':
            case ':':
            case ';':
            case '(':
            case ')':
            case '{':
            case '}':
            case '[':
            case ']':
            case '!':
            case '@':
            case '#':
            case '$':
            case '%':
            case '^':
            case '&':
            case '*':
            case '\\':
            case '/':
                break;
            default:
                sb.Append(c);
                break;
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Компактностью тут, конечно, и не пахнет, но эффективность достойная.

Comment: Привели бы примеры цифр для полноты картины. (Хотя автора, по-моему, волнует исключительно компактность кода.)

Comment: @andreycha Да я с радостью. Выполняется примерно в 5 раз быстрее, чем заранее скомпилированный `Regex`.